# Unexpected number in JSON at position 346348

Tags: json, syntax-error, azure-data-factory, azure-rm-template

I'm getting the following error when deploying a Data Factory ARM template

> ##[error]Error: Ensure the Template file ( 'filepath\ARMTemplateForFactory.json' ) is valid. Task failed while
> parsing with following error: Unexpected number in JSON at position
> 346348

I've viewed and validated the JSON using this [JSON lint](https://jsonlint.com/). No errors reported.

My question is, how can I navigate to **position 346348** to investigate?

I've googled and checked the multiple answers on SO but nothing is helpful.  The majority of the answers suggest that a number that begins with 0 is invalid.

I'm going through the template file to view anything that begins with zero in the most recent commit and this is one example.

[image]

Is this wrong?

I don't want to post the whole template here - it's over 12k lines - and I don't want to spend time trying to anonymise it.

Comment: I suggest you selectively delete pipelines until the error goes away. Then inspect that pipleine. It might also be in a linked service etc. Or you could open it as a text file in something like powershell and use cmdlets to snip out the text around position 346348

Comment: @Nick.Mc  I used Notepad++ GoTo feature to get at position 346348.  The issue was with the trigger configuration.  Thanks for the idea.

Comment: It would be fantastic if you could post an answer including a snippet of sample JSON so that this could help anyone else. It's interesting that the editor allows you to enter this data but it fails deployment